# Make QSpinBox react to mouse wheel events when cursor is not over it

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

I am using `Qt 5.3.2` with `Qt Creator 3.2.1` with `MinGW 4.8.2` on `Windows 7`. I have a `QSpinBox` and can change its value with the mouse wheel only if the mouse is over the `QSpinBox`. If the mouse is not over the `QSpinBox`, scrolling the mouse wheel has no effect, even though the `QSpinBox` still has focus. What do I need to do to be able to change values in the `QSpinBox` that has focus with the mouse wheel even if the mouse is not hovering over it? Setting `mouseTracking` to `true` does not have that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eventFilter` to do this. Install it on your `mainWindow`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        QWheelEvent *wheelEvent = static_cast<QWheelEvent *>(event);
        if(wheelEvent->delta() > 0)
            ui->spinBox->setValue(ui->spinBox->value() + 1);
        else
            ui->spinBox->setValue(ui->spinBox->value() - 1);
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj,event);
}
```

It is just example, so you can improve it as you want.

Or use this:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        QApplication::sendEvent(ui->spinBox,event);
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj,event);
}
```

In this example, when you detect wheel event, you send it to your spinbox.

But don't forget

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

As [DmitrySazonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035613/dmitry-sazonov) recommended. We will detect `wheelEvents` when our spinBox is in focus, when spinBox loses focus, we don't react on `wheelEvent` (other widgets react as normal). We do this in one `eventFilter`.

To do this, provide new `bool` variable. For example:

```
private:
    bool spin;//in header
```

Initialize it in constructor:

```
spin = false;
```

And your `eventFilter` should be:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == ui->spinBox && event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
        spin = true;
    
    if(spin)
    {
        if (obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
        {
            QApplication::sendEvent(ui->spinBox,event);
        }
    }
    if(obj == ui->spinBox && event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
        spin = false;

    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj,event);
}
```

Or just do this, without an additional variable:

```
if (obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
{
    if(ui->spinBox->hasFocus())
        QApplication::sendEvent(ui->spinBox,event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not mention it in the question but I have more that one `QSpinBox` and testing them all seems sub-optimal, so I need a generic message forwarder. Based on the [Chernobyl's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041722/3484570) I made my own version of the message filter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if (obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        auto focusWidget = QApplication::focusWidget();
        if (focusWidget){
            qApp->removeEventFilter(this);
            QApplication::sendEvent(focusWidget, event);
            qApp->installEventFilter(this);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This forwards all `QWheelEvent`s to the `QWidget` with the focus. One could also add other events that need to be forwarded.

The `qApp->removeEventFilter` and `qApp->installEventFilter` inside the event filter is the only way I found that prevents the event filter calling itself when scrolling on the main window causing a stack overflow (condition `focusWidget != this` does not help). There isprobably a way to prevent the infinite recursion without reinstalling the event filter on every `QWheelEvent`.