# Determine mouse event: hover leave parent for child widget

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qevent, qmouseevent

I have 2 widgets, a parent and a child widget:

[image]

Having access to the implementation of the `red` widget, is it possible to determine the moment when the cursor hovers out of the `red` widget into the `blue` widget without implementing any event handlers or deriving the `blue` widget?

The red area has a well defined thickness(e.g. 5px).

Comment: what you want to do with this information? If you want only change appearance of widget then `setStyleSheet` should do the job.

Comment: i don't want just appearance. i would need the cursor to change in when the mouse enters and leaves the area. the problem is that when the cursor leaves the area i want to reset it to its previous form

Comment: so just set [cursor property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop) on both widgets.

Comment: I understand but I need a different cursor for each edge. the function is very handy but it will provide me only one cursor type. I would like the red area to be a border with which you can resize the window

Comment: for such functionality I would add a separate widget for each edge and merge it only visually.

Comment: it would be too much painful...it would need 8 widgets(4 for the edges and 4 for the corners), i was hoping for a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you cannot catch the *transition* without catching one mouse move event from the red widget and one mouse move event from the blue widget, since the mouse can jump on screen and may not move in a continuous fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Without deriving: use event filter, QEvent type is HoverEnter and HoverLeave.

With Stylesheet

```
QWidget:hover{}
```

Comment: Tried `if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter) { qDebug() << "Hover enter"; }` inside the `QWidget::event` for the red widget but it doesn't show anything...

Comment: @JacobKrieg I provided many answers with event filters on SO. So Please check one of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041471/make-qspinbox-react-to-mouse-wheel-events-when-cursor-is-not-over-it/26041722#26041722 It describes how to install filter abd use it. Try it. Is it work?

Comment: I wouldn't use event filters because I would like it to work without knowing what is the name of the blue...qwidget. I would like the blue qwidget to be configurable by the user and to let him add it...i see the eventfilter approach a bit hackish...

Comment: @JacobKrieg if it is widget then you can set special object name and When you find that some object in event filter has this special name(you know this name, you set this name, not user)then you know that it is widget which you need.